# Using two main panels from one 200 Amp service meter

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I bought a small shop in Tennessee. I was forced to rewire it as the code inspector said, "This was the best of the wiring in 1945. It's never going to pass an inspection in 2019". I have rewired the entire shop, passed my electrical inspection and everything has been great since 2019.

I have 200 Amp four wire three phase in a Delta configuration with the "B" phase at 208 volts and "A" and "C" phase at 125 volts.

The only three phase device in my whole shop is my three phase compressor. Everything else is single phase and the only things running solely on the 208 volt leg is my two min-split a/c systems which are fairly low amperage. (I have a device installed to measure the amount of amperage each leg is drawing that I can pull up on my laptop) It's very rare to see even 80 amps being used and that was a test with the compressor on both a/c units running and we activated both lifts at the same time, which is scenario that realistically never happens.

Now I want to build an addition on to my shop but I'm out of spaces in my breaker box. Ideally what I would like to have is a bus bar that I could power with all three phases and the power each of my two panels, (the existing one and the one that I want to install next it) with 2|0 gauge wire.

My service disconnect is 1 foot from my existing panel. The new panel will be one foot from the existing panel and four feet from the service disconnect. (the disconnect is directly behind the meter with just a concrete wall in the middle). This would make a short bus bar easy to set u inside of a box.

I have no lugs on my Eaton CH type service panel to power another panel as a sub-panel. If I use a 100 amp breaker to power the sub-panel I would not be able to get 2|0 wire into the breaker and I don't even think that I could get a 100 amp ch breaker anyway.

Both of my panels would receive more than enough amperage with 2|0 stranded copper wire but I don't know how to accomplish this. The furthest device on my system would be my dynomometer that will be 75 foot of wire away from my panel and require approximately 30 amps at 220V.

I really need to expand my shop with this 55' x 35' expansion project but I need to be able to figure out the specifics on how to Get the power to the new section and what it's going to cost before I begin construction. Any help and possible links to get the equipment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Web search shows 100A CH breaker easy to find. It does max out at 1/0, but 1/0 will do 100A in aluminum at 60°C on up to 150A in copper at 75C, so it's more than adequate for a 100A breaker.

Comment: I really appreciate your input. It honestly would be a lot easier to just sub-panel with a 3phase breaker on the bottom right of the panel. I would be able to just shoot 1|0 over to the new panel and go. The bottom breaker is also the closest to my current input wiring from the service disconnect.    That is also where the three small wires for my current meter reside so both panels would be monitored with no changes and the without having to buy anything except the breaker, wire and the new panel making my costs lower as well.

Comment: I guess that I am a little paranoid about voltage drop as I repair vehicles and operate in a mostly DC voltage world. LOL

Comment: Sub panel is the obvious answer, but the title is asking if you can double tap a meter socket. Which is a maybe? https://www.electriciantalk.com/threads/double-tap-a-200amp-meter-legal-or-not.276550/ - one of those comments says you *shouldn't*; a 'sub' panel that can light you up after you turn the 'one' main off.

Comment: No, you can only branch past the main breaker.

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing panel please?

Answer (score 4):

> If I use a 100 amp breaker to power the sub-panel I would not be able to get 2|0 wire into the breaker and I don't even think that I could get a 100 amp ch breaker anyway.

CH3100 breakers are definitely in the catalog. whether your local supplier has them in stock, I couldn't say.

I don't know why you're talking about 2/0 wire. That stuff is 175A in copper and 135A in aluminum. No need for that on a 100A feeder.

100A feeder requires #1 (no oughts) aluminum, or #3 copper if cost is no object.  Should fit in a 1-1/4" conduit.

Anytime you install 2 panels next to each other, connect them with ***several*** conduits. You use these for a) the feeder wire, and b) any pass-throughs that may be convenient.  Also, since they are metal conduit, they carry ground and no additional ground wire is needed.

> I have no lugs on my Eaton CH type service panel to power another panel as a sub-panel.

No problem. Pick any circuits that occupy 3 consecutive spaces on your existing CH panel.   Remove those breakers from the panel.  Now you have a place to put your 3-pole 100A breaker in the main panel for your feeder to the subpanel.

Hold on. What do you do with the circuits you just pulled out of the panel?  Easy. Re-route them over to the new subpanel via those conduit pass-throughs I mentioned.  Those circuits will live in the new subpanel now. If the wires can make it with existing length great. Otherwise splice them with wire nuts and pigtails to extend them. **If you bring over hot wires, you MUST bring over neutral as well** and land it on the neutral bar of the subpanel (unless it's a G/AFCI breaker, in which case you know the drill).

Standard conduit wiring rules apply.

> I guess that I am a little paranoid about voltage drop as I repair vehicles and operate in a mostly DC voltage world. LOL

Oh. Voltage drop is 20 times worse for 12 volts than 240V.  *Think about it. If you have 4 volts drop on 12V, that's terrible. If you have 4 volts drop on 250V who cares?*

If we're thinking about useful power (running a 2000 watt gadget), voltage drop is *400 times worse* on 12V (20 squared).  Because amps is 20x and voltage is 1/20 so every percent bites that much harder.

I don't even bother doing a 240V voltage drop calculation until at least 175'.

> Now I want to build an addition on to my shop. The issue that I have is that I want to be able to safely use my welder at any lift in the new shop. I normally feed each lift with number six wire and then run a disconnect with a twenty amp breaker for each lift and let the fifty amp breakers in the main box provide power to the plug in box for the welder on each lift.

That's a fine way to do it.  If you want to save some $ at the cost of larger conduit, feel free to use #2 aluminum for all feeders up to 90A.  At these large sizes, it is proven to be safe. It's my "go to" for subpanels larger than 30A.

2 rules with aluminum. #1 you must use terminals *properly* rated for aluminum. Subpanel lugs are.  #2 you must torque the terminals to the torque value stated on the lug or instructions (don't use something out of a machinist's book, the lug is made of aluminum not steel).  I hardly need to explain the importance of torque to a mechanic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. My electrical friend that observed all of my work and then signed off as the electrician on the job initially suggested that I fold over enough wire on my low amperage runs so that if I needed to move them to another panel. I spoke with him yesterday on this same project and his suggestion was the same as yours except he said that with my two hundred amp service that he would put or keep all of my heavier loads in the main box, (instant on hot water heater, welder/ lift outlets, three phase compressor, microwave plug, etc.), and keep light loads on the sub.